# SSIS Logging showing random behaviour while logging event in dbo.syssisLog table

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, ssis-2012

I was planning to use SSIS logging to get task level details (duration of running, error message thrown-if any, user who triggered the job ) for my package.

SSIS was creating dbo.syssisLog table under System table and it was working just fine. Suddenly it stops creating table under System table and start creating under Users table. Also now it is not logging some events which were logged previously when created under System table. Events like: PackageStart and User:PackageStart/User:PackageEnd event for some tasks.

Can anyone please guide me what's going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

The table showing under System versus User tables is fairly meaningless but if you want the table to show the same, set it as a MS shipped table

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sysssislog'
```

The way database logging works in the package deployment model, is that SSIS will attempt to log to dbo.sysdtslog90/dbo.sysssislog (depending on your version) but if that table doesn't exist, it will create it for you. There is a copy of that table in the `msdb` catalog which is marked as a system object. When SSIS creates its own copy, it just has the DDL *somewhere* in the bowels of the code that does logging. You'll notice it also creates a stored procedure `sp_ssis_addlogentry` to assist in the logging.

As for your observation for inconsistent logging behaviour, all I can say is I've never seen that. The only reason it won't log an event is if the event doesn't occur - either a precursor condition didn't happen or the package errors out. If you can provide a reproducible scenario where it does and then doesn't log events, I'll be happy to tell you why it does/doesn't do it.